# What do you call an Electrical Engineer who specializes in micro-components?

Tags: terminology

My son wants to study electrical engineering, but with focus on design of small personal electronics like VR, earphones, action cams, etc. I would think a degree in electrical engineering would be a first step, but is there a field of study that will allow him to focus on these types of micro-electronics? Audio-visual electronic engineer?

Comment: The things you have just listed are full-blown products consisting of a whole bunch of different electronic and other components. So the whole spectrum of engineers might be needed for developing these (except, perhaps, robotics)

Comment: Darn it, I was expecting the punch line to a dirty joke.... But this really isn't an appropriate question here. You are asking about opinions.

Comment: To some extent it depends on the school and what concentrations they offer: power, device physics, VLSI, etc.  Not all schools will offer all of them.  The good news is that you usually have a year or two of basic classes like physics, circuit analysis, signals and systems, and so on before you really start down the road to a specialization and your son can then decide what best suits his fancy with a little clearer idea of what each of them entail.  But like other people have said, there isn't one specialization for this, it's multiple specializations working together.

Comment: There isn't such a thing. But it is ***very*** common for children to want to "do that" and point to a cell phone or virtual reality headsets. These are not specialties, but commercial products. A corresponding answer to your son would be to "find a job at Microsoft in their 'virtual reality lab'" or something similar. These groups will have specialists. But the specialists well be about some specific aspect (human eye optics, human color perception, high impact plastics injection molding, etc.) In any case, there's lots of time to resolve this.

Comment: FWIW, it is usually really unimportant the specific field a fresh grad were specializing in, as it is absolutely insufficient for the industry in most cases and the potential employers will look more for the general understanding, learning abilities and soft skills.

Comment: I don't expect this Q to stay open. That said, specializing in small devices brings in a number of disciplines: VLSI design, power design, RF, networking, user interface, electro-optics, materials, etc. The kind of person who leads these kinds of projects will have strong skills in at least several of these, as an 'architect'. Such a person should also have strong software skills in addition to hardware knowledge.

Comment: The EE studies can have a focus on many number of things you can select from, in this case, major subject should be Embedded Systems or something similar, but each uni is different what they offer. Some might even have a Personal Electronics group.

Comment: squinty ........

Comment: Thx all for your amazing responses.. really gives some great insight. We’ll start looking at collages and talking to some of the facualty staff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a electronics engineer.
Since the major covers a vast knowledge of electronics components and theories which serve an important part of the "small personal electronics" that you mentioned.
At least that's what I studied for my electronics engineering degree.

Answer (score 1):

The basic undergraduate qualification is for Electronics Engineering. Some institutions will cover that in the Electrical Engineering or even the overall Engineering faculty.

Any deeper specialisation might begin with a course module, but is likely to be a postgraduate line of study. Either way, your son has to get on the undergraduate course first, and then specialise in slower time.